# How do I iterate over a list that could be added to by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a list that I iterate over and perform some actions on. One of the actions that can be performed can result in work being passed off to another thread, which may add more elements to my list while I'm still iterating over it in the first thread.

Is there a way for me to iterate over the list in such a way that the iterator includes the additions from the other thread?

Here's some pseudo Java

```
Class1{

   List multiThreadList = getMyList(); //points to list in Class2
   for(Element element:multiThreadList)
      //perform some actions, these actions may results in another thread being called
      //which will cause addToMyList() to be called while I'm still iterating over it
      //I want to keep iterating if an element gets added on the other thread
}
Class2{
   List originalList = new ArrayList();

   public getMyList()
     return originalList;

   void addToMyList(Element element)
     originalList.add(element);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: You could convert the list to an array, you could place a shared lock around the list. You could use a synchronised list

Comment: it really depends on your exact requirements, you might be able to get away with no locks, you might need locks. Can there be deletes from the list during iteration, right after it, can ```addToMyList``` take a long time to add stuff to the list?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk there are no deletions to the list during iteration, only additions, it's possible for addToMyList to take a long time which is why I don't want to wait an arbitrary unit of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure List is the kind of collection you need?

I would use BlockingQueue, and remove elements from BlockingQueue in one Thread, and add in another. This way you would not need any additional concurrency control.

```
BlockingQueue<String> bounded   = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

bounded.put("Value");

String value = bounded.take();
```

Your pseudo code becomes

```
Class1{

   BlockingQueue queue = getMyList();
   Object element = queue.poll(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   while(element != null) {
      //perform some actions, these actions may results in another thread being called
      //which will cause addToMyList() to be called while I'm still iterating over it
      //I want to keep iterating if an element gets added on the other thread  
      element = queue.poll(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
Class2{
   BlockingQueue originalList = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

   public BlockingQueue getMyList()
     return originalList;

   void addToMyList(Element element)
     originalList.put(element);
}
```

But one thing, you need to understand, that this task in current form would give you inconsistent results. Since you don't control another Thread, your iterator might finish, before new element was added, and you will miss it, while iterating, depending on the state of the system you can miss from zero to all new elements. So you either need to join all created Threads, before you finish iterating, or change the approach.

Comment: +1. Note that "blocking" refers to `take`. Your consumer will wait until an element to process is available (which is what you probably want anyway). `put` does not need to wait.

Comment: I like this, tell me (since I'm new to concurrency) is this an example of making it asynchronous?

Comment: It is asynchronous in that you have two (or more) threads. One puts in stuff, one processes it.

Comment: In other words this could very easily devolve into a timing issue, is there anyway to do it synchronously then, I want to avoid arbitrary timeouts

Comment: Not really. Things are processed in the order they are put into the queue. You don't want to shut down the consumer before all producers are done. Maybe also look at CompletionService for asynchronous computations.

Comment: Hi Thilo, sorry for the extended discussion I just want to be clear on this. If I implement it in this fashion is it not possible that thread2 could take too long on its "preprocessing" I'll call it, before adding a new element to the list and thus I'll finish iterating on thread1 without going through all the elements I need to (which I think would make it a timing issue). Is there a way for me to monitor when thread2 sleeps or finishes?

Comment: If you start Threads while iterating, you don't have control over which new Thread adds message first to the Queue. It might be that last started Thread added message before the earlier one. So you have no guarantees on the order of messages in the Queue, and I would not make any assumption there. You can impose some ordering, though with PriorityBlockingQueue, but that's a different story.

Comment: For timing issue, you can join Thread 2, this way you'll wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use some type of concurrency control mechanism, such as a Mutex lock, a semaphore, or a monitor. These create a 'critical section' of your code which would allow only one thread to access it at a time.

Unfortunately, there is no solution to the problem without somehow locking the code and making a portion of it serial.